# navigationOptions in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on React Native and I have unclear image with navigationOptions.
What is navigationOptions and How can I overlay a component like drawerOpen. And can I use many drawerOpens?

Thanks for your kind attention.[image]

Comment: Did you read [**the docs**](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options)?